# Shouldn't $parsers/$formatters be run at a different place rather than link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AFAIK— the `link` function in angular is for "*registering DOM listeners as well as update the DOM.*"

But looking at this [*sample*](http://plnkr.co/edit/UQ5q5FxyBzIeEjRYYVGX?p=preview) :

```
app.directive('changecase', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      //format text going to user (model to view)
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return value.toUpperCase();
      });

      //format text from the user (view to model)
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return value.toLowerCase();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I see many examples out there that uses the link function in order to "*firewall*" bad values *into* the model and *out* to the view.

**Question**

This is not manipulating dom nor dealing with  listener.

It just seems to me as a  weird place  - to put those "firewalls" in the `link` function

Is it the *right* place to put $parsers/$formatters  ?

Comment: I am wondering if there is any way to push formatter/parsers in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AFAIK— the link function in angular is for "registering DOM listeners
>   as well as update the DOM."

Such rules are not carved in stone, they always result from practical considerations. Pre-link and post-link functions are the places where the one can get his hands on required controller (ngModel).

So yes, `link` is the right place to do that.